# How can we limit a user to see and run only specific JFrog Pipelines?

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

Can we assign role based access control (RBAC) rules to control which users can access and run which pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RBAC for JFrog Pipelines is integrated with JFrog Access. Pipelines sources can be attached with various permissions to allow admins to control access.

Refer documentation [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Permissions#Permissions-PipelinePermissions)